# Лучший метод оптимизации функции многих переменных

Tags: алгоритм, функции, оптимизация

Есть задача оптимизации (минимизации) функции многих переменных. функция имеет множество локальных минимумов, поэтому на ум приходят стохастические методы, по типу дифференциальной эволюции (ДЭ), но нигде не смог найти зависимость скорости схождения ДЭ от кол-ва параметров функции, т.е. размерности задачи. Собственно вопрос: какой алгоритм использовать?
Параметры задачи:
1) Моделируется кристалл в каждой точке которого есть магнитное направление. От взаимного расположения этих направлений зависит энергия. Задача - найти кристалл с минимальной энергией.
2) Много локальных минимумов.
3) Очень желательна возможность распараллеливания алгоритма.
4) Чем больше размерность - тем лучше. Минимум - 32х32х8 параметров, что уже довольно много.

Answer (score 2):

### Поиск глобального оптимума.

Задача, о которой идёт речь, довольно сложна и в общем случае не имеет полного решения, кроме как методом перебора. Если у вас нет дополнительных данных о задаче, то решать придётся исключительно стохастическими методами.

Какие могут быть дополнительные данные. Например известно, что оптимизируемая функция принадлежит какому-нибудь "хорошему" классу (например полиномиальна). Подобная информация позволяет найти какие-нибудь зависимости, которые позволят разработать алгоритм исключительно под вашу функцию.

В общем случае, как выше было написано, помогут только стохастические методы. Однако следует понимать, что они не гарантируют нахождение решения, к счастью, чаще всего, это не так существенно. Дело в том, что зачастую значения оптимизируемой функции вычисляются как результат работу некого численного алгоритма, а это значит, что если есть две далеко отстоящие точки `a, b`, такие, что `f(a) < f(b)`, но не сильно: `|f(a) - f(b)| < eps`, то не ясно, обусловлена ли эта разница действительно тем, что точка `a` лучше, или же это следствие погрешности алгоритмов.

Более того, чаще всего на практике не требуется прямо совсем оптимальное решение, можно вполне удовлетвориться просто "достаточно хорошим" решением, и стохастические алгоритмы вполне могут нам это обеспечить. Представьте, например, решение [задачи коммивояжёра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0), если она решается для прикладных целей, то не обязательно совсем минимизировать общую длину пути, достаточно просто, чтобы путь был достаточно хорош и не слишком затратен, а в этом случае задача уже может быть разумно решена.

### Возможные алгоритмы.

*[Алгоритм дифференциальной эволюции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)*

Хороший алгоритм, мне пришлось его реализовать и довольно много гонять на сложной функции, которая имела огромное число пиков. Алгоритм показал себя отлично, успешно находил оптимум функций за достаточно низкое время. Алгоритм хорошо работает с задачами большой размерности, если правильно подобрать его параметры (о подборе параметров могу написать, но там довольно много будет).

Однако следует понимать, что этот алгоритм заточен под решение конкретной проблемы алгоритмов оптимизации - для овражных функций. Это означает, что в общем случае нет причины использовать именно его, и разумно будет попробовать другие алгоритмы.

В моём случае - я просто взял первый попавшийся алгоритм, дальнейшие эксперименты показали, что это был не лучший выбор, хотя и довольно хороший.

*[Алгоритм имитации отжига](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)*

Очень интересный алгоритм. Он хорошо себя зарекомендовал в решении задач комбинаторной оптимизации, в том числе ранее упомянутой [задачи коммивояжёра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0). Алгоритм хорош тем, что ему совсем не нужно никаких априорных допущений о функции, она может быть хоть всюду разрывной (но нужно понимать, что мы получим решение в соответствии с выбранной точностью вычислений, если специально делать подлянку алгоритму - он выдаст чепуху).

Я пробовал реализовать его, но недолго, эксперименты закончились плохо - моя реализация достигала ответа дольше, чем алгоритм дифференциальной эволюции, и с не очень большой точностью и вероятностью, то есть из 10 запусков 3-4 стабильно оказывались совсем мимо. Скорее всего это была проблема именно реализации, не советую судить об алгоритме именно по моему опыту, тем более, что по сути эксперименты я не завершил.

*[Метод Монте-Карло](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE)*

Простейший стохастический метод. Про него даже есть теоремы о вероятности сходимости. Чувствителен к качеству ГПСЧ.

*Широкий класс [генетических алгоритмов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC)*

Их довольно много, вы и сами можете придумать свой вариант. Алгоритм дифференциальной эфолюции, кстати, один из них. Тут поле для экспериментов огромно.

### Итоги.

Больше я, пожалуй, продолжать не буду, алгоритмов очень много. В вашем случае я бы попытался довести до ума метод имитации отжига, это как ответ на вопрос:

> Собственно вопрос: какой алгоритм использовать?

На вопрос из заголовка:

> Лучший метод оптимизации функции многих переменных

ответ не воодушевит - такого метода не существует (на текущий момент). Но не всё так плохо, конкретные прикладные задачи вполне можно решить, если не требовать сверхъестественных результатов, ссылки выше вам в этом помогут.